# Задача с матрицей

Tags: python

Условие и мой код ниже:

Дана матрица A размером NxN, заполненная неотрицательными целыми числами. Расстояние между двумя элементами Ai j и Ap q определено как |i - p| + |j - q|.

Требуется заменить каждый нулевой элемент матрицы ближайшим ненулевым. Если есть две или больше ближайших ненулевых ячейки, нуль должен быть оставлен.

Ограничения: 1 <= N <= 200, 0 <= Ai j <= 1 000 000.

Входные данные
В первой строке содержится число N. Затем идут N строк по N чисел, разделённых пробелами и представляющих собой матрицу.

Выходные данные
Выводится N строк по N чисел, разделённых пробелами, - модифицированная матрица.

Код:

```
from copy import deepcopy
size = input()
size = int(size)
s = 0
new = []
result = []
for x in range(int(size)):
    a = input().split()
    new.append(a)
#Приводим все элементы матрицы к типу int, чтобы не писать это постоянно в коде
new = list(map(lambda x: list(map(int, x)), new))
#Копируем массив без ссылок
result = deepcopy(new)
for i in range(len(new)):
    for j in range(len(new[i])):
        if new[i][j] == 0 and size > 1:
            #Правый верхний угол
            if (j == size - 1 and i == 0):
                if (min(new[i][j - 1], new[i + 1][j]) == 0):
                    result[i][j] = max(new[i][j - 1], new[i + 1][j])
            #Левый нижний угол
            elif j == 0 and i == size - 1:
                if (min(new[i - 1][j], new[i][j + 1]) == 0):
                    result[i][j] = max(new[i - 1][j], new[i][j + 1])
            #Левый верхний угол
            elif i == 0 and j == 0:
                if (min(new[i + 1][j], new[i][j + 1]) == 0):
                    result[i][j] = max(new[i + 1][j], new[i][j + 1])
            #Правый нижний угол
            elif i == size - 1 and j == size - 1:
                if (min(new[i - 1][j], new[i][j - 1]) == 0):
                    result[i][j] = max(new[i - 1][j], new[i][j - 1])
            #Верхняя грань
            elif (i == 0 and (j > 0 and j < size - 1)):
                a = []
                a.extend([new[i][j + 1], new[i][j - 1], new[i + 1][j]])
                a = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, a))
                if (len(a) == 1):
                    result[i][j] = a[0]
            #Нижняя грань
            elif (i == size - 1 and (j != 0 and j != size - 1)):
                a = []
                a.extend([new[i][j - 1], new[i][j + 1], new[i - 1][j]])
                a = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, a))
                if (len(a) == 1):
                    result[i][j] = a[0]
            #Левая грань
            elif j == 0 and (i != 0 and i != size - 1):
                a = []
                a.extend([new[i + 1][j], new[i - 1][j], new[i][j + 1]])
                a = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, a))
                if (len(a) == 1):
                    result[i][j] = a[0]
            #Правая грань
            elif (j == size - 1 and (i != 0 and i != size - 1)):
                a = []
                a.extend([new[i + 1][j], new[i - 1][j], new[i][j - 1]])
                a = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, a))
                if (len(a) == 1):
                    result[i][j] = a[0]
            #Середина
            elif i != 0 and i != size - 1 and j != 0 and j != size - 1:
                a = []
                a.extend([new[i + 1][j], new[i - 1][j], new[i][j - 1], new[i][j + 1]])
                a = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, a))
                if (len(a) == 1):
                    result[i][j] = a[0]
for m in result:
    m = map(str, m)
    print(' '.join(m))
```

У меня выходит лишь на 30 баллов из ста.Я не понимаю почему, вроде все правильно.Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Первая проблема - новая матрица получается из старой. Мы сначала пересчитываем новые значения элементов, а потом, записываем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тестировал на [acmp.ru](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=status&id_t=621&id_mem=218575). Встречал такие же задачи на других сайтах, там ограничение по времени `1с`. [Логика решения](http://www.cyberforum.ru/pascal/thread1369835.html)

Получился такой код: (проходит 11 тестов, не успевает за `0.5с`)

```
n = int(input())
a = []
b = []
is_null = True
for row_index in range(n):
    a.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
    b.append(list(map(str, a[row_index])))
    if any(a[row_index]):
        is_null = False

if not is_null:
    for row_index, row in enumerate(a):
        for col_index, value in enumerate(row):
            if value > 0:
                continue
            r = 1
            while True:
                count = 0
                score = ''

                # quarter 0

                x = col_index - r
                y = row_index
                num = 0

                if x < 0:
                    offset = abs(x)
                    if row_index + x < 0:
                        offset = r
                    x += offset
                    y -= offset
                    num += offset

                while (num < r) and (y > -1):
                    if a[y][x] > 0:
                        count += 1
                        score = str(a[y][x])

                    if count > 1:
                        break

                    x += 1
                    y -= 1
                    num += 1

                if count > 1:
                        break

                # quarter 1

                x = col_index
                y = row_index - r
                num = 0

                if y < 0:
                    offset = r
                    if col_index + abs(y) < n:
                        offset = abs(y)
                    x += offset
                    y += offset
                    num += offset

                while (num < r) and (x < n):
                    if a[y][x] > 0:
                        count += 1
                        score = str(a[y][x])

                    if count > 1:
                        break

                    x += 1
                    y += 1
                    num += 1

                if count > 1:
                    break

                # quarter 2

                x = col_index + r
                y = row_index
                num = 0

                if x > n - 1:
                    offset = r
                    if row_index + (x - n + 1) < n:
                        offset = x - n + 1
                    x -= offset
                    y += offset
                    num += offset

                while (num < r) and (y < n):
                    if a[y][x] > 0:
                        count += 1
                        score = str(a[y][x])

                    if count > 1:
                        break

                    x -= 1
                    y += 1
                    num += 1

                if count > 1:
                    break

                # quarter 3

                x = col_index
                y = row_index + r
                num = 0

                if y > n - 1:
                    offset = r
                    if col_index - (y - n + 1) > -1:
                        offset = y - n + 1
                    x -= offset
                    y -= offset
                    num += offset

                while (num < r) and (x > -1):
                    if a[y][x] > 0:
                        count += 1
                        score = str(a[y][x])

                    if count > 1:
                        break

                    x -= 1
                    y -= 1
                    num += 1

                if count > 0:
                    if count == 1:
                        b[row_index][col_index] = score
                    break

                r += 1

for row in b:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

---

Тот же код на <kbd>C++</kbd>: (**Accepted**)

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector< std::vector< int > > a(n, std::vector< int >(n, 0));
    std::vector< std::vector< int > > b(n, std::vector< int >(n, 0));

    int k = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            std::cin >> a[row][col];
            b[row][col] = a[row][col];
            if (a[row][col] == 0) {
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (k > 0 && k < (n * n)) {
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
                if (a[row][col] > 0) {
                    continue;
                }

                int r = 1;
                while (true) {
                    int counter = 0;
                    int score = 0;

                    // quarter 0

                    int x = col - r;
                    int y = row;
                    int step = 0;

                    if (x < 0) {
                        int offset = std::abs(x);
                        if ((row + x) < 0) {
                            offset = r;
                        }
                        x += offset;
                        y -= offset;
                        step += offset;
                    }

                    while ((step < r) && (y > -1)) {
                        if (a[y][x] > 0) {
                            counter++;
                            score = a[y][x];
                        }

                        if (counter > 1) {
                            break;
                        }

                        x++;
                        y--;
                        step++;
                    }

                    if (counter > 1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    // quarter 1

                    x = col;
                    y = row - r;
                    step = 0;

                    if (y < 0) {
                        int offset = r;
                        if ((col + std::abs(y)) < n) {
                            offset = std::abs(y);
                        }

                        x += offset;
                        y += offset;
                        step += offset;
                    }

                    while (step < r && x < n) {
                        if (a[y][x] > 0) {
                            counter++;
                            score = a[y][x];
                        }

                        if (counter > 1) {
                            break;
                        }

                        x++;
                        y++;
                        step++;
                    }

                    if (counter > 1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    // quarter 2

                    x = col + r;
                    y = row;
                    step = 0;

                    if (x > (n - 1)) {
                        int offset = r;
                        if ((row + (x - n + 1)) < n) {
                            offset = x - n + 1;
                        }

                        x -= offset;
                        y += offset;
                        step += offset;
                    }

                    while (step < r && y < n) {
                        if (a[y][x] > 0) {
                            counter++;
                            score = a[y][x];
                        }

                        if (counter > 1) {
                            break;
                        }

                        x--;
                        y++;
                        step++;
                    }

                    if (counter > 1) {
                        break;
                    }

                    // quarter 3

                    x = col;
                    y = row + r;
                    step = 0;

                    if (y > (n - 1)) {
                        int offset = r;
                        if ((col - (y - n + 1)) > -1) {
                            offset = y - n + 1;
                        }

                        x -= offset;
                        y -= offset;
                        step += offset;
                    }

                    while (step < r && x > -1) {
                        if (a[y][x] > 0) {
                            counter++;
                            score = a[y][x];
                        }

                        if (counter > 1) {
                            break;
                        }

                        x--;
                        y--;
                        step++;
                    }

                    if (counter > 0) {
                        if (counter == 1) {
                            b[row][col] = score;
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    r++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            std::cout << b[row][col] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Все работает, заметил свои ошибки, спасибо!